# Domino Server Crash

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Domino server is crashing frequently and here is the nsd log. There is big xpage based application on the server and accessed by many users always. All nsd logs are having such lines common.
[image]

Details one:
 [image]
Please help.

Comment: What version of IBM Domino? and have you applied the latest fix packs?

Comment: Domnio version is 8.5.3 FP4

Comment: Does the NSF include a message like "PANIC: LookupHandle: Handle out of range"?

Comment: It appears to be crashing while reading a view. Have you tried running updall -R on all databases touched by your application?

Comment: Yes "PANIC: LookupHandle: Handle out of range" message is there as per comment from admin team.

Comment: Yes we are using updall -R; additional information is we are using count by category in xpage views using the approach mentioned here http://xcellerant.net/2013/07/10/fix-indenting-on-multiple-categories-in-a-view-panel/

Comment: An updall will not prevent the crash. "PANIC: LookupHandle out of range" means you have to fix your code. It's not anything to do with the documents in the database other than there are too many for the code to iterate over on that version of Domino without proper recycling.

Answer (score 3):

Looks as if it is failing when reading view entries...

Not specific to XPages I have seen similar behaviour when there is a corrupt document in a database. So I would suggest as the very first thing that you run a fixup and compact on the database(s) with your application. If your application is fulltext-indexed I would consider deleting and regenerating the fulltext index. I have also seen crashes due to corrupt FT-indexes (though years ago).

Next, there are a couple of important Fixpacks to 8.5.3 that you should consider - I know it may not always be that easy to do - depending on your environment.

If none of that solves the issue I would:

1. Consider ANY changes done in the environment or the application shortly before the crashes started - even though they may not seem related.
2. Report the issue to IBM as a support incident. They do have some people that are very clever at digesting all the NSD information and put the finger on the issue.

Hope you get it solved!

/John

*PS: You should REALLY consider getting any servers running XPages up on the latest version of Domino (i.e. 9.0.1 FP3/FP4). There are MAJOR improvements - and you can use the openNTF.org Domino API to improve any Java coding you do in your XPages (and you really should use a lot of Java - instead of SSJS). Just a free advice ;-)*

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We will apply fixup and update.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the message "PANIC: LookupHandle: Handle out of range", you are not recycling Domino objects correctly.

- Always recycle `ViewEntry` and `Document` within loops
- Always recycle `Name` or `DateTime` objects created within loops
- If the view includes dates/times in columns and you use `getColumnValues()`, always load the columnValues() object into a Vector variable before using it and always recycle the Vector object afterwards using the .recycle(Vector) method available on any Domino object. Never, ever use `getColumnValues(0)` unless the view does not contain DateTimes and never will. Any call to `getColumnValues()` extracts all the columns and, for dates/times, creates a DateTime object which is a child of the Session, **not** of the ViewEntry. So recycling the ViewEntry has no effect on the DateTime.

John's two other suggestions will probably also help. OpenNTF Domino API always recycles, so you don't have to, so you *cannot* get this kind of crash. Later versions of Domino increase the number of handles available, so the chances of getting this crash are minimised.

Comment: We are using http://dontpanic82.blogspot.in/2010/01/xpages-three-ways-to-build-search.html approach to conduct FTSearch in custom search page where in one place getColumnValues() has not been recycled but that had been running with out crash for last 7 months. In all other cases variables like doc etc are recycled in loop. Also if you are saying about recycle issue hope it points to memory leakage. But we never encounter any performance issue or slowness at all in the application.

Comment: In addition to this we earlier faced some crashes due to some mime programming in postSaveEvent lotusscript agent with "PANIC: LookupHandle: Handle out of range". We fixed that in code for the same and it was not at all memory issue.

Comment: Mime entities are also Domino objects and also children of the Session, if I remember correctly. But postSaveEvent only handles a single document per request, so would not cause the problem.

Comment: Please understand that recycle is nothing to do with memory leakage. Memory is not leaking. Accessing a Domino object from SSJS / Java requires a handle to the underlying C++ object. There are a finite number of handles. Any call gets the next available handle. If you don't recycle, it cannot re-use those handles, and if you use enough **in the same request**, you run out. At the end of each request, the Session is recycled, and recycling a Domino object also recycles all descendants, so everything is recycled. It's been blogged about at length.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your explanation. I have one more question: if sign out would take place then does it release all handles created in that last session by the user? Also is there any specific way to see if JVM memory is exhausted or reached to the max handles once crash happens?

Comment: I'll blog about it, but handles are only available for the current request. You cannot keep handles for the life of a user session, which is why you can't store Domino objects in any scopes above requestScope. Seeing JVM memory would not tell you anything about the handles. There are two different things. You can hit the limit of handles without exhausting Java memory and vice versa. You'll need to check the web or IBM to see if there are any diagnostic tools regarding handles, but it's really down to effective recycling.

Comment: I wanted to mean if user opens multiple pages in multiple tab then would session out free all JVM memory for all these pages?

Comment: JVM memory (consisting of scoped maps, component trees held in memory etc) would be retained for current time + XPages timeout, both for closing the browser and doing an HTTP logout. There's no way to instantly clear the memory of session Java memory if the browser is just closed or if doing an HTTP logout. It's possible to clear the sessionScope map, there are XSnippets for that. But the size is usually negligible compared to the available memory for the JVM (and each NSF has its own JVM).

Comment: Hello Paul, we had face a crash again but we had added recycle in all necessary loop. Crash note is PANIC: LookupHandle: handle not allocated. Any clue please.

Comment: "handle not allocated" is a different cause, but I'm not familiar with causes. IBM technotes may offer some suggestions.

Comment: I can in nsd Out of Memory for these two tasks ; does it give any clue?<@@ ------ Notes Memory Summary -> Conclusion (Time 10:23:53) ------ @@>
[nHTTP: 1720]: Out of Memory
[nntask: 1444]: Out of Memory